# In Operations Dashboard, how do you get the widgets to adjust when you click on a point on your map?

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I created a dashboard with several different widgets. They do update when I add filters to the layers. However, when I click on a point (school) all that happens is that the point is highlighted. When I right click, I can "show pop up" and other things. What I want to do is for the widgets to update when I click on any one point.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to configure your widget's properties, and under Data Source, chose your layer with Selection.

That should enable your widgets to work off the selected features.

Comment: When I configure the widget, it does adjust when I click on a point. However, when I don't click on a point, the widget is completely blank. I would like the widget to not be blank, but still adjust when clicking on a point.

Comment: It's either one or the other, Operations Dashboard's built in widgets cannot currently do what you state. It is possible to create your own widgets using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF or the Javascript API, there you may be able to configure that sort of action.